# Eclipse travado na tela workspace laucher

Tags: eclipse, jdk, workspace

Faz uns dias que não consigo abrir o Eclipse após instalar a **JDK 8**. A tela de seleção de *workspace* trava e não consigo fazer nada.

Acabei de instalar o **JDK 8**, acabei de descompactar um novo **Eclipse**, nunca abri o mesmo, não tem *plugin* instalado, não tem a pasta `.metadata`, e mesmo assim trava na seleção de *workspace* quando abre o **Eclipse**.

O erro no *Event Properties* do Windows é esse:

---

[![The program eclipse.exe version 0.0.0.0 stopped interacting with Windows and was closed. To see if more information about the problem is available, check the problem history in the Security and Maintenance control panel.
 Process ID: 1240
 Start Time: 01d215d37852a303
 Termination Time: 14
 Application Path: C:\JAVA\Aplicativos\eclipseJUNO\eclipse.exe
 Report Id: c6fda0bf-81c6-11e6-9c14-28c2dd8de649
 Faulting package full name: 
 Faulting package-relative application ID:][1]][1]

---

Alguém ja viu isso ?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tenta baixar o NEON, O Juno não é o mais novo.

Comment: Oi Giuliana, primeiramente gostaria de agradecer a atenção. 

Eu tenho 3 versões distintas, NEON, MARS e JUNO, mas qualquer uma ocorre o mesmo problema. Até hoje não entendi o motivo desse problema. Eu percebi que no Windows 10, se eu executo como ADM, da certo, mas no Win 7 não. Mistério ainda, pois os Eclipses funcionavam normalmente.


Não sei também se tem algo a ver, mas eu tentei mudar o NOME da máquina para acessar uma base de dados que é protegida e liberada para o nome do host mais o nome da base, depois desse dia, parou, mas eu voltei o nome e não deu certo mais.

Comment: Não tem relação com o nome da máquina. Faz o seguinte, executa o inicializador do eclipse do prompt de comando. Assim quando der o erro o eclipse vai printar a stacktrace e aí poderemos identificar a causa.

Comment: Acho que vou até colocar como concluído. O problema ocorreu "acho" que devido a uma atualização automática do Java, pois eu uso 64 bits, e a atualização colocou 32 bits na pasta "C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java", mais precisamente a pasta "javapath".  Eu deletei essa pasta e o eclipse rodou. eu vi essa indicação em outro post.

Comment: Não precisa colocar "resolvido" no título, seria bom criar uma resposta com o procedimento que resolveu o problema, depois vc pode "aceitar" a resposta que significa que o problema foi resolvido.

Comment: Não adicione RESOLVIDO no titulo, leia a recomendação do @rray

Comment: @EvertonGodoy por favor, não fique adicionando RESOLVIDO no titulo, o site nao é um forum, visite [tour] para ver como funciona o site e veja os comentarios acima.

Comment: Se tiver um tempo recomendo a leitura de [O que significa quando uma resposta é "aceita"?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) e [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/91)

Comment: Ok, desculpa. att.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se Ao clicar no atalho do Eclipse, o mesmo não abrir ou ficar travado na tela do Workspace Launcher, talvez pode ter ocorrido atualização do Java com incompatibilidade de 32 / 64 bits.

Vá até o diretório:
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java

Delete a pasta "javapath"

Problema similiar ao abaixo.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461607/cant-start-eclipse-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-13

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Ola, tem que excluir o arquivo .lock dentro do diretório ECLIPSE/workspace/.metadata. Fazendo isso ele abre.